Broken Recursive Typing for Python
I have a type alias that I call point2d and a related recursive type alias.
point2d = tuple[float, float]

point2d_nested = (
    point2d
    | list["point2d_nested"]
    | tuple["point2d_nested", ...]
)

Now I want to write a function that will scale points in any nested structure by a factor. For example, scale_nested((1,1), 2) == (2,2) or scale_nested([(1,1), (1,1)]) == [(2,2), (2,2)]. Here's an implementation:
def scale_nested(points: point2d_nested, factor: float) -> point2d_nested:
    """
    Scales a list of lists of points by a given factor.
    Weird things happen if you supply 3D points or if your point is not a tuple.
    """
    if not points:
        return points

    # We've bottomed out at a point
    if (
        isinstance(points, tuple)
        and len(points) == 2
        and isinstance(points[0], (int, float))
        and isinstance(points[1], (int, float))
    ):
        return points[0] * factor, points[1] * factor

    if isinstance(points, list):
        return [scale_nested(p, factor) for p in points]

    if isinstance(points, tuple):
        return tuple(
            scale_nested(p, factor) for p in points if not isinstance(p, (int, float))
        )

    raise ValueError(f"Something is an invalid type: {points}")

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:
knots = [((1.0, 2.0),)]
scale_nested(knots, 2) # <- knots look red

Argument of type "list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "points" of type "point2d_nested" in function "scale_nested"
  Type "list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]" cannot be assigned to type "point2d_nested"
    "list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]" is incompatible with "point2d"
    "list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]" is incompatible with "list[point2d_nested]"
      Type parameter "_T@list" is invariant, but "tuple[tuple[float, float]]" is not the same as "point2d_nested"
      Consider switching from "list" to "Sequence" which is covariant
    "list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]" is incompatible with "tuple[point2d_nested, ...]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) knots: list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]


Did you consider switching from "list" to "Sequence" as the error message said?

As suggested by Pyright/Pylance, your code will work as-is with Sequence instead of list:
(playground)
from collections.abc import Sequence

point2d_nested = (
    point2d
    | Sequence["point2d_nested"]
    | tuple["point2d_nested", ...]
)

knots = [((1.0, 2.0),)]  # list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]
scale_nested(knots, 2)   # fine

However, note the type of scale_nested(knots, 2). It is revealed as:
tuple[float, float] | Sequence[point2d_nested] | tuple[point2d_nested, ...]

...otherwise known as point2d_nested.
However, we can do better than that (arguably). Use a TypeVar to tell the type checker that the return type will be exactly the same as the input type, as long as it is compatible with point2d_nested:
(playground)
T = TypeVar('T', bound = point2d_nested)

def scale_nested(points: T, factor: float) -> T:
    ...

# PEP 695 syntax
def scale_nested[T: point2d_nested](points: T, factor: float) -> T:
    ...

knots_1 = [((1.0, 2.0),)]
reveal_type(scale_nested(knots_1, 2))  # list[tuple[tuple[float, float]]]

knots_2 = ((1.2, 3.4), (5.6, 7.8))
reveal_type(scale_nested(knots_2, 2))  # tuple[tuple[float, float], tuple[float, float]]

knots_3 = ([(1.2, 3.4)], [(5.6, 7.8), [(9.1, 2.3)]])
reveal_type(scale_nested(knots_3, 2))  # tuple[list[tuple[float, float]], list[tuple[float, float] | list[tuple[float, float]]]]

knots_4 = [('foo', 'bar')]
reveal_type(scale_nested(knots_4, 2))  # error

knots_5 = ([(1.2, 3.4)], [(5.6, 7.8), [9.1, 2.3]])
reveal_type(scale_nested(knots_5, 2))  # error


How would you implement def scale_nested(points: T, factor: float) -> T:? I believe it is not possible to copy arbitrary sequence subclasses.

@Wombatz "Practicality beats purity". From a type checking standpoint, such a T is arguably better than point2d_nested.

I don't agree. Putting a collections.deque into the function will be returned as some kind of sequence but mypy will tell you it is a deque. Accessing deque methods then will result in a runtime error. The type hints are lying - you will realise that once you have to use "type ignores" in the implementation. I agree that point2d_nested is not a nice type to handle. It would be cool if the concrete sequences where down cast to Sequence but i don't think that is possible with the type hint system in python.

My python version is 3.9 so I can't use type_1 | type_2  syntax, I used
from typing import Union
point2d_nested = (Union[point2d ,
                        list["point2d_nested"] , 
                        tuple["point2d_nested", ...]])

and your code worked as it is.
